# Box C# object as generic interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have a significant amount of viewmodels, each designed for one specific object type (e.g. Person, Car, whatever). I would like to add generic functionality to these, e.g. the ability to check if a viewmodel already exists that contains a specific object (contains a specific Car, Person, etc.). I'd like to be able to create the ViewModels dynamically (e.g. create viewmodel for Car, viewmodel for Person). All viewmodels will have different functionality, commands, etc. and so I cannot simply use one global viewmodel. Is it possible to use an interface for this problem, or is this a fundamentally flawed design pattern?

Current code:

```
namespace DummyNameSpace
{

    public interface IViewModel<T>
    {
        T DataModelObject { get; set; }
        string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class SomeDataModelObject
    {
        public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public class ViewModelInstance : IViewModel<SomeDataModelObject> //There will be various ViewModels that implement IViewModel, all with different 'T' types.
    {
        //Some properties, commands, etc.
    }

    public class TheMainViewModel //won't implement IViewModel, as this will be used to control all the various other viewmodels.
    {

        public void MethodBeingCalled(object viewmodelinstance)
        {
            Type type = viewmodelinstance.GetType();
            var x = (viewmodelinstance as IViewModel<type>).DataModelObject = null; //Will do other things here.
        }
    }
}
```

The current code doesn't work, as I can't use "x as IViewModel(type)". Is there a different way of boxing 'x' so that I can access it through the interface?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use a `Type` instance as a generic argument - it has to be compile-time type.

Change your `MethodToBeCalled` like this:

```
public void MethodBeingCalled<T>(IViewModel<T> viewModelInstance)
{
    var x = viewModelInstance.DataModelObject;
}
```

In general, generics tend to propagate through your code-base. While dynamic generics dispatch *is* possible, it always involves reflection - which is usually completely unnecessary.

Comment: `var x = viewModelInstance.DataModelObject = null;` makes no sense though. `x` will always be `null`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Yeah, I got rid of it just a sec before you posted your comment :D

Comment: Adding the 'null' was a bad example from my side :-) This is exactly what I was looking for, and what I have implemented. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on not changing the signature of your method, then you need to use 'getInterface' and 'getGenericTypes' methods to do the checking and then use reflection to actually set the value.

```
 var interf = viewmodelinstance.GetType().GetInterface("IViewModel`1");

 var argType = interf.GetGenericArguments()[0];
```

Comment: Thanks Braim, I'll keep this in mind should I come across this issue in future.